# "Parallel" vectors in higher dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, lagrange-multiplier

$\bf a, b, x$ are n-dimensional vectors. Given that every point $\bf x$ that satisfies $\bf a\cdot x$ $=0$ also satisfies $\bf b\cdot x$$=0$, where we are using the dot product and $\bf b$ is not zero. Prove that $\bf a$$=k\bf b$, where $k$ is a scalar constant.

Background:

I'm trying to convince myself that the Lagrange Multiplier method makes sense (I'm currently limiting my effort to single constraint), and I'm able to boil it down to this lemma. However, I did not phrase my question in the context of Lagrange Multiplier because I think this is just a general lemma that works for other context as well.

I know my question works for $n=2, 3$ because eg when $n=3$, the points $\bf x$ which satisfies $\bf a\cdot x$$=0$ forms a plane with normal $\bf a$. Extending this logic further, we see that $\bf a$ and $\bf b$ are parallel and the result holds. But the idea of perpendicular and parallel breaks down for $n>3$, so I don't know how to proceed for higher dimensions.

Comment: "The idea of perpendicular breaks down" is not true, and this is exactly the way one proves this: you  absolutely are going about this the right way, so well done. Technically your hypothesis is $\langle a\rangle^\perp \leqslant \langle b\rangle^\perp$. So 
 you will get $\langle a\rangle^{\perp\perp} \geqslant \langle b\rangle^{\perp\perp}$; and as $X^{\perp\perp}=X$ you're home.

Comment: Hi. I don't understand why is my hypothesis $\langle a\rangle^\perp \leqslant \langle b\rangle^\perp$ and what that means. Can you elaborate or give some keywords to for me to research?

Comment: @nextQuestion Technically as you've written it the claim is false. If $\mathbf{a}\ne\mathbf{0}$ but $\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{0}$, then certainly the hypothesis is true because $\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ is always true, but $\mathbf{a}\ne k\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{0}$ for any scalar $k$.

Comment: @nextQuestion Also, ancient mathematician is referring to what's called the "orthogonal complement" of the subspaces spanned by the two vectors, which is what you can use to solve the correctly stated problem.

Comment: The words I'd look for are Dual Spaces, Annihilators, and (in Inner Product Spaces, Orthogonal Complements). This infrastructure would let you give a technically correct proof  along the lines you are following, even for the case of $k$ constraints.

Comment: Thanks all. After some quick research, I understand why my hypothesis is $\langle a\rangle^\perp \leqslant \langle b\rangle^\perp$ and why that leads to $\langle a\rangle^{\perp\perp} \geqslant \langle b\rangle^{\perp\perp}$. I couldn't understand why $X^{\perp\perp}=X$ yet, though I get why if that's true, it means "I'm home". Will also be researching on the terms to settle the case for k constraints.